# Backbone.js listenTo issue, Object [object Object] has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm going really mad for a thing:

```
var BoardNumber = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            value: 0,
            selected: false
        };
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.save({selected: !this.get("selected")});
    }
});

var BoardNumberView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "li",
template: _.template('<div class="boardNumber"><p>{{value}}</p></div>'),

events: {
    "click .boardNumber": "toggleDone",
    "click .selected": "toggleDone"
},

initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},

toggleDone: function (evt) {
    this.model.toggle();
}
});

var NumbersOnBoard = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: BoardNumber,
toGenerate: 80,
url: "/numbers",
initialize: function(){
    var i = this.toGenerate;
    while(i--){
        this.create({ value: this.toGenerate-i });
    }
},
selected: function(){
    return this.where({selected: true});
}
});
```

and nothing else should be necessary.. when I click on it, there is this error in the title, I don't really know what it can be

EDIT: Added collection and complete view.
Note: the click launches the event this.render perfectly, and only then is lanunching the error and it's like the event listener from that model disappears.

EDIT #2: For the stack trace, In the development version of Backbone it shows:

```
triggerEvents              backbone.js:205
Backbone.Events.trigger    backbone.js:146
_.extend._onModelEvent     backbone.js:933
triggerEvents              backbone.js:206
Backbone.Events.trigger    backbone.js:147  
_.extend.set               backbone.js:370
```

Comment: Could you put it in a fiddle? Right now it seems like something is missing. What about the template for the view?

Comment: Something is going on in the parts you're not showing us, the basic structure (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kKPB2/) seems fine.

Comment: Thank you, I added other parts..

Comment: Can you also show the code where you are initializing these models

Comment: Do you mean the HTML? is all just a skeleton, the scripts are all in order - jquery, underscore, backbone, models, collections, views, routers, and init, are all in this order, initialized below. above the re is, in the middle of the others, this: <div id="numbers-board"></div>

Comment: In `BoardNumberView#initialize`, do a `console.log(this.model)` and see if it's actually a Backbone model or not

Comment: it is, I did console.log everywhere and compared them also with the ToDo app, NOTHING different, really. It looks everything nice and fine, just it doesn't work. I saw around it can be about the fact that this.model should be a function, but, how?

Comment: You use `.save` on your toggle function does this has anything to do with ajax success/error callbacks rather than within your model/view stuffs? Do you override Backbone.sync?

Comment: No I don't, actually I would like to use only the local version of the array without saving it.. is it possible? because maybe there can be some problems with it

Comment: look at the fiddle from `mu is too short` you can simply `.set()`. Anyway, your browser should show stack trace and you should be able to pin point which object exactly that causing your problem right?

Comment: I think that the problem is the interaction with the collection.. I even add a localStorage to save it. No, set does the same effect and in the stack trace there is a fallback here: 
 this.model.set({selected: !this.model.get("selected")});

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything intrinsically wrong with the code you've posted, so it's safe to assume the root cause is in some missing initialization code.

I was able to use your code, making some assumptions about what how it was supposed to work:

1. You're rendering a list of items generated by the `NumbersOnBoard` collection.
2. This list of items is created and saved to the database when the collection is new'd up.
3. Each model in the collection is being rendered inside a parent view of some sort.
4. This parent view appends each child's view to the DOM somewhere, probably in it's own container
5. The models represent some kind of selectable item; their state changes when clicked and immediately persists to the DB

Assuming this is all true, [this fiddle demonstrates it successfully issuing a GET request on click](http://jsfiddle.net/ccamarat/E2s2A/). To make it work I added a CollectionView that was responsible for rendering each `BoardNumberView`.

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    itemView: BoardNumberView,
    children: [],
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection = options.collection;
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(child) {
            var view = new self.itemView({
                model: child
            });
            view.render();
            self.children.push(view);
            self.$el.append(view.$el);
        });
        return this;
    },
    close: function() {
        while (this.children.length) {
            var child = this.children.pop();
            child.close();
        }
    }
});

var collection = new NumbersOnBoard();
var cv = new CollectionView({
    collection: collection
});

$('body').append(cv.render().$el);
```

Answer (score 0):

For rendering a list of items, I would recommend using [Backbone Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette), which makes all the boilerplate code written in the example.

In that case `BoardNumberView` will be an `ItemView`, and the collection rendering view would be a `CollectionView` or a `CompositeView`.

Its documentation is quite simple, but if You want further investigation I would recommend the [posts of David Sulc](http://davidsulc.com/blog/category/backbone-js/backbone-marionette/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone for your replies, I've just found what was wrong in it. In the parent View of BoardNumberView, in the initialization there was this code:

```
this.listenTo(numbersOnBoard, 'change', this.addAll());
```

that was firing the wrong event. It all worked when I changed it to:

```
this.listenTo(numbersOnBoard, 'reset', this.addAll());
```

And I somehow understand why, looking at the code of Backbone. Someone knows how it works in Backbone and explain it in simple passages?

Thank you another time, really.

EDIT: NO, was the fact that i was passing this.addAll() instead of this.addAll